# Creating triangular UIRegions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

I need to separate the screen into regions that look like this (separated by black lines): [image]

The documentation says `Most regions are rectangular or elliptical in shape, but you can use the methods of this class to create more complex shapes by adding, subtracting, and intersecting other regions.` I can't figure out how to create these.

For context I am trying to replicate the [StickyCorners: Using UIFieldBehavior and other UIDynamicBehaviors](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/StickyCorners/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demo, but adding 4 more sticky points, 1 at each midpoint (indicated by red circles).

Comment: In these triangles, what do you want the behaviour to be, of the red balls?